# DatetimeIndex for daily data only in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a custom index based on daily dates, such as:

```
a = bdate_range('1990-01-01', freq='D', periods=10)
```

This will create an index with various Timestamp objects:

```
>>> a[0]
Timestamp('1990-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D')
```

Unfortunately the Timestamp class seems to initialize the underlying `numpy.datetime64` objects every single time with an [ns] flag, i.e. enabling a granularity down to nanoseconds.

This is a total overkill for my data, which requires only **daily** **granularity**. Not only that, but allowing for this much granularity restricts the data to start only after the year 1678! (i.e. `Timestamp('1677-01-01')` will fail). The solution should be that one can somehow set a flag that determines which datetime64 resolution the Timestamp object should use, e.g. something like:

```
Timestamp('1990-01-01', dtype='datetime64[d]')
```

and ideally bdate_range or date_range should have a similar flag that one can set, in order to create a whole index of adequately formatted Timestamps.

So long story short, is it possible in pandas to create some type of index (e.g. DatetimeIndex, or maybe DateIndex?) that that is specifically suited to handle daily data only?

Thank you for your replies

Comment: what do you mean overkill? if you're dealing with days, there really aren't that many that have occurred for something where you'd have daily data... (e.g. what are you measuring the daily change in for the year 1677? and what's the quality of that data?) are you worried about performance? because you should NOT be worrying about this prematurely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the internals of DatetimeIndex are closely tied to a nanosecond resolution, so I don't think there's much that can be done there.

But, as recommended in the "caveats" section of the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#minimum-and-maximum-timestamps), a PeriodIndex can be used to represent dates outside the nanosecond resolution.

```
In [147]: a = pd.period_range('1990-01-01', freq='D', periods=10)

In [148]: a[0]
Out[148]: Period('1990-01-01', 'D')
```

Comment: This is actually really good! I somehow missed that in the documentation. Thanks